# Redirect to another page JavaScript with condition

Tags: javascript

i have the following code which works just fine in redirecting.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
window.location.replace('https://google.com/');}, 3000);
}
```

what i need is that the code checks the previous page (history) and if it was, for example, `https://gmail.com`, go to `https://google.com` and if it was something else go to, for example, `https://facebook.com`.

Comment: `document.referrer` will tell you what page the user just came from ..  There is also `window.history` but it does not provide URLs .. Just whether or not the user can go **page back** or **page forward**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.referrer` will tell you what page the user just came from ..  There is also `window.history` but it does not provide URLs .. Just whether or not the user can go **page back** or **page forward**

Something like this should do what you are asking.

```
console.log(document.referrer);  // View this to view what JS "sees" as actual referrer.

 window.onload = function () {

    if (document.referrer == 'https://gmail.com') {
        setTimeout(window.location.replace('https://google.com/'), 3000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(window.location.replace('https://facebook.com/'), 3000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it's worth noting that `document.referrer` may be empty if the last page the user visited doesn't allow sending referrer information with the current page (e.g. via `Referrer-Policy`), so it's not a good idea to rely on `Referer`/`document.referrer`.

Comment: @D. Pardal   --  Exactly.  That's a good point.  There is really no way around it.  What if they organically arrive at the page?  What if user settings prevent it ..  Even server side wouldn't help in this case.